# How to give 'points' to the user mentioned

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to give 'points' to the user @mentioned and have the number of points stored in a .json file. My code is not outputting any errors and command is not outputting anything, I'm not sure if I'm using the member.mention.id (if that exists) wrong etc.

command: >addpoints @mention amount(number)

```
@bot.command(help="Give points to a user")
async def addpoints(ctx, member: discord.Member, amount: int):

  if str(member.mention.id) not in list(pts['points']):
    pts['points'][str(member.mention.id)] = 0 #Adds user to data list if not in it yet with 0 pts

    pts["points"][str(
      member.mention.id)] = pts["points"][str(member.mention.id)] + amount  #points in data file + amount of points added
    save_pts() 
    await message.add_reaction("✅")
```

Other code to 'save the data' (I have a different event that uses this same code, so I believe it should work, but I have put below), FYI I am using replit, which is what os.environ is about

['ptsbase_path'] is the pts.json file

```
pts = {"points": []}

def save_pts():
  open(os.environ['ptsbase_path'], 'w').close()
  with open(os.environ['ptsbase_path'], "w") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

#code above

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  global data, guild

  guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, id=int(000000000000)) #server id

  if os.path.isfile(os.environ['ptsbase_path']):
    with open(os.environ['ptsbase_path'], encoding="utf-8") as file:
      pts = json.load(file)

  else:
    save_pts()
```

Comment: Did you enable message intent on your discord bot / py file? By default, discord bots don't get access to every message.

Comment: Yes it should be, I have used the same bot to do a similar points event triggered by a message / bot.event , but i never had to manually "give" points

Comment: @Alsatian, [welcome to Stack Overflow.](/tour) Check if my comment below helps, so I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Alsatian, your code looks incomplete. `pts['points'][str(member.mention.id)] = 0 #Adds user to data list if not in it yet with 0 pts

    pts["points"][str(
      member.mention.id)] = pts["points"][str(member.mention.id)] + amount` can be replaced by `pts['points'][str(member.mention.id)] = amount`. I guess `pts` isn't global. So, you're not saving anything in `save_pts()`, because you're saving `data`, and `data` is not what you want to save. `open(os.environ['ptsbase_path'], 'w').close()`: why this line? And you need elif/else for `if str(member.mention.id) not in list(pts['points']):`.